# Arithmetic precision with doubles in Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, double, precision

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how the precision of these doubles affects the outcome of arithmetic operations in Matlab. I thought that since both a & b are doubles they would be able to carry out operations up to that precision. I realize there can be round-off error but since these numbers are well within the 64-bit number representation I didn't think that would be an issue.

```
a = 1.22e-45
b = 1
a == 0
   ans = 0  %a is not equal to zero
(a + b) == 1
   ans = 1
```

How come it is able to carry enough precision to recognize a != 0 but when added to 1 it doesn't show any change.

Answer (score 6):

64-bit IEEE-754 floating point numbers have enough precision (with a 53 bit mantissa) to represent about 16 significant decimal digits.  But it requires more like 45 significant decimal digits
to tell the difference between (1+a) = 1.00....000122 and 1.000 for your example.

Comment: I think the mantissa has 52 bits (11 bits for exponent, plus 1 bit for the sign making a total of 64-bit). An excellent article by *Cleve Moler* (author of the 1st version of MATLAB) explains all the details of floating point numbers: [PDF link] http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/pdf/Fall96Cleve.pdf

Comment: @Amro:  There's an implied leading "1" bit, unless the number is denormalized.  So Jim's right, in most cases (and certainly for these numbers).

Comment: Thank you. I still have a ways to go in understanding number representations in computers.

Comment: @Drew Hall: you're absolutely right, the normalized representation has the form `±(1+f)*2^e`... my bad :)

Comment: @Amro--easy to forget--after all, it's not really there! :) (Plus, in my answer, I was remembering it as 48 bits for some reason.  The old brain's not what it used to be...:))

Answer (score 6):

"Floating" point means just that--the precision is relative to the scale of the number itself.

In the specific example you gave,  1.22e-45 can be represented alone because the exponent can be adjusted to represent 10^-45, or approximately 2^-150.

On the other hand, 1.0 is represented in binary with scale 2^0 (i.e., 1).

To add these two values, you need to align their decimal points (er...binary points), meaning that all of the precision of 1.22e-45 is shifted 150-odd bits to the right.

Of course, IEEE double precision floating point values only have 53 bits of mantissa (precision), meaning that at the scale of 1.0, 1.22e-45 is effectively zero.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what the other answers have said, you can use the MATLAB function [EPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) to visualize the precision issue you are running into. For a given double-precision floating-point number, the function [EPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) will tell you the distance from it to the next largest representable floating point number:

```
>> a = 1.22e-45;
>> b = 1;
>> eps(b)

ans =

  2.2204e-016
```

Note that the next floating point number that is larger than 1 is 1.00000000000000022204..., and the value of `a` doesn't even come close to half the distance between the two numbers. Hence `a+b` ends up staying 1.

Incidentally, you can also see why `a` is considered non-zero even though it is so small by looking at the smallest representable double-precision floating-point value using the function [REALMIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/realmin.html):

```
>> realmin

ans =

  2.2251e-308  %# MUCH smaller than a!
```