# Matlab gives wrong answer

Tags: matlab, precision, numerical

If the following code is executed MATLAB makes a mistake. Can someone verify this?

```
floor([0.1:0.1:2]/0.01)
```

So what is the 129 doing here??

```
ans = 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 129 140 150 160 170 180 190 200
```

Comment: 129. That sneaky bastard.

Comment: Maybe I'm splitting hairs, but couldn't you just have done `10:10:200`?

Comment: related: [About floating point precision: why the iteration numbers are not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6478526/97160)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a floating point rounding error because of the colon-generated vector. 
Like Rasman said, if you do:

```
floor((0.1:0.1:2 + eps) / 0.01)
```

There will be no rounding errors.

However, based on [how the colon operator works](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/?solution=1-4FLI96), I suggest that you do the same calculation like this:

```
floor([(1:20)/10] / 0.01)
```

[***Edit***: *following Rasman's comment, I will add that the latter approach works for negative values as well, while adding `eps` sometimes fails*]

The bottom line is that it is better using the colon-operator with *integer* numbers  to minimize rounding errors.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably doing a floating point calculation resulting in an inexact value of 129.99999999999999... something instead of 130. and then you floor it to 129.

Answer (score 4):

it's a rounding approximation brought on by the array construction. The solution would be to add eps:

```
floor([0.1:0.1:2]/0.01+ eps([0.1:0.1:2]/0.01))
```

Comment: Thank you, is this a workaround for this specific situation? Or do you recommend this kind of code always in such cases?

Comment: Most of the time I've seen a rounding problem it is because it is off by a single least significant bit (perhaps 2, although I can't recall seeing one. You can be super-safe by adding 2*eps, but for this type of problem it works:  `any((floor([0.1:0.1:200]/0.01 + eps([0.1:0.1:200]/0.01))) - (10:10:20000))`

Comment: I take that back, it works while you are in positive territory

Comment: @EitanT I completely disagree, you're trying to add a value-specific eps, not some generic number. Use my example and compare: `any((floor([0:0.1:2]/0.01 +eps)) - (0:10:200))` vs `any((floor([0:0.1:2]/0.01 +eps([0:0.1:2]/0.01))) - (0:10:200))`

Comment: @Rasman +1 for beating me to the answer with `eps`, and +1 for the comment on the negative values ;) About the second comment, look at what I wrote in my answer, in the first approach. Add the `eps` to the colon-generated vector, _before_ the division.