# Really simple MATLAB code with illogical results

Tags: matlab

Below is my MATLAB code to generate imaginary part of wavespeed (c), using function oscalcpcf when Reynolds number is 249 and I want to run for wavenumber (alpha) between 0.1 to 2 in steps of 2.

```
c1holder = [];
c2holder = [];
reyholder = [];
alphaholder = [];
wantedrey = [];
wantedalpha = [];
for Rey = 249
    for alpha = 0.1:0.1:2
        c1=oscalcpcf(Rey,alpha,100);
        c2=oscalcpcf(Rey,alpha,200);
        c1holder = [c1holder c1];
        c2holder = [c2holder c2];    
        reyholder = [reyholder Rey];
        alphaholder = [alphaholder alpha];      
    end
end
vectors = [c1holder' c2holder' reyholder' alphaholder'];
```

The above code is not difficult at all in my opinion but my laptop went cranky for some pairs of Reynolds number and alpha. Just naming one of them, `Reynolds number = 249` and `alpha = 0.3`.

When I run the above code, I get `c1 = 6.06002472332094E-08` and `c2 = 0.0000010870344982811`.

Now here's the problem. If I run from `2` to `0.1` with steps `-0.1`, I get `c1 = -0.337584041016646` and `c2 = 0.0000364854401656638`.

AND if I were to check manually using `oscalcpcf`, ie `oscalcpcf(249,0.3,100)` and `oscalcpcf(249,0.3,200)`, I get `c1 = -0.337583911335139` and `c2 = -0.337577395716528`.

I have really no idea what's going on here can someone please help!

EDIT

```
alpha: 2.000000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.899999999999999900000000000000
alpha: 1.800000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.700000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.600000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 1.500000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.399999999999999900000000000000
alpha: 1.299999999999999800000000000000
alpha: 1.200000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.100000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 1.000000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 0.899999999999999910000000000000
alpha: 0.799999999999999820000000000000
alpha: 0.699999999999999960000000000000
alpha: 0.599999999999999870000000000000
alpha: 0.500000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 0.399999999999999910000000000000
alpha: 0.299999999999999820000000000000
alpha: 0.199999999999999960000000000000
alpha: 0.099999999999999867000000000000
```

and for `0.1` to `2`

```
alpha: 0.100000000000000010000000000000
alpha: 0.200000000000000010000000000000
alpha: 0.300000000000000040000000000000
alpha: 0.400000000000000020000000000000
alpha: 0.500000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 0.599999999999999980000000000000
alpha: 0.700000000000000070000000000000
alpha: 0.800000000000000040000000000000
alpha: 0.900000000000000020000000000000
alpha: 1.000000000000000000000000000000
alpha: 1.100000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 1.200000000000000200000000000000
alpha: 1.300000000000000300000000000000
alpha: 1.400000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 1.500000000000000200000000000000
alpha: 1.600000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 1.700000000000000200000000000000
alpha: 1.800000000000000300000000000000
alpha: 1.900000000000000100000000000000
alpha: 2.000000000000000000000000000000
```

OMG, why doesn't my computer give precise steps of `0.1` when I told it to do so. The function `oscalcpcf` is very sensitive to small changes in the `alpha` and when I check these values that my script uses, it matches if I do it manually by `oscalcpcf`. Could you suggest a way for my computer to give precise steps of `0.1`? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what `oscalcpcf` is doing we can only guess. Depending on how sensitive the function is to its input your problem could be precision. Try adding the line `disp(['alpha: ' sprintf('%.30f',alpha)]);`to your inner for-loop to see what the actual value of `alpha` is.

Comment: Actually, perfectly logical results, once you understand how computers do arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a floating point error because of your colon-generated `0.1:0.1:2` vector.

You get inaccurate values for `alpha`, because computers can't represent all numbers exactly given a fixed storage size such as double precision. This is especially true with the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html#f1-85254), which makes the inaccuracy propagate through the vector elements.

Now, I'm not sure whether this improves your results or not, but based on [how the COLON operator works](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/?solution=1-4FLI96), I would suggest that you try to run your loop as following (similar to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931099/1336150)):

```
for alpha = ((1:20) / 10)
```

Also, if `oscalcpcf()` is a function which is allowed to be tampered with, I suggest you look into it and improve its robustness/sensitivity to small changes in the input. A 10<sup>-14</sup>% inaccuracy should by no means have a significant impact on your results.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but inaccuracies still exist... I wonder if there's any way to create precise vectors of step size 0.1 at all..

Comment: Unfortunately not. I suggest you work on `oscalcpcf` to be less sensitive.

Comment: NO. Read the responses. You cannot represent the number 0.1 EXACTLY in floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
alpha = ((1:20) *1e-1). you should get :

0.100000000000000005551115123126 
0.200000000000000011102230246252 
0.300000000000000044408920985006 
0.400000000000000022204460492503 
0.500000000000000000000000000000 
0.600000000000000088817841970013 
0.700000000000000066613381477509 
0.800000000000000044408920985006 
0.900000000000000022204460492503 
1.000000000000000000000000000000 
1.100000000000000088817841970013 
1.200000000000000177635683940025 
1.300000000000000044408920985006 
1.400000000000000133226762955019 
1.500000000000000000000000000000 
1.600000000000000088817841970013 
1.700000000000000177635683940025 
1.800000000000000044408920985006 
1.900000000000000133226762955019 
2.000000000000000000000000000000
```

The results would be accurate to the double precision standard.
Also, `sym` and `vpa` functions in  [matlab symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/vpa.html) may help if u have it.