# diff function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I know `diff` calculates the discreete derivative, or let's say the difference between consequitive components of a vector.

Not I define a variable

```
x=-4:1/10:4;
y=diff(diff(x));
```

Why the heck do I get `1.e-15*` and a row of vectors that are non zero? Matlab is being honest by displaying that somehow, in calculating `x=-4:1/10:4;` it had rounded some digits and though while I execute `y=(diff(x));` only and even though it displays all digits same, it some how shows that in it's core they are not stored as same quantities(because it rounded off -4+0.1 or some quantity as other than -3.9 ???). Now, how do I get the standard output? How do I get 0 when it is really zero, like in this case, and non zero whatever it may be like even like `1*e-...`, when it is actually non zero?

*Note* if that is not possible, how do I calculate real/actual `diff(x,2)`, or atleast accurate sign and zero when diff is actually zero? and get the real discreete derivative for functions like `cosine` instead of some misleading value?

I need to calculate inflection point using diff.

Comment: b/c of numerical precision.

Comment: Another victim of floating point inaccuracy. Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699596/is-this-a-matlab-bug-do-you-have-the-same-issue) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930750/matlab-gives-wrong-answer).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am aware of this numerical precision. I just needed a way to solve this. Thanks Everyone. Just could not spell the exact works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this is because of floating point precision, which is given in MATLAB by [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) (*i.e*, epsilon). Any result you get will be this accurate, not more. Regarding your question, you can prettify the result by rounding all elements or by zeroing almost-zero elements out. For instance, to set all elements small then 10ε to zero:

```
y = diff(x, 2);
y(abs(y) < 10 * eps) = 0;
```

For more details, see the answers of the duplicate questions.